# Django-compress not getting javascript

Tags: javascript, python, django, templates

I am using [Django-compress](http://code.google.com/p/django-compress) to compress my css and js files. Relevant snippets as follows.

settings

```
COMPRESS = True
COMPRESS_VERSION = True
COMPRESS_CSS = {
    'css_all': {
        'source_filenames': (CSS_ROOT + 'main.css', 
                             CSS_ROOT + 'jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.css', 
                             CSS_ROOT + 'ui.daterangepicker.css',),
        'output_filename': 'css/all_compressed.r?.css',
    }
}

COMPRESS_JS = {
    'js_all': {
        'source_filenames': (JS_ROOT + 'daterangepicker.jQuery.js', 
                             JS_ROOT + 'jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.min.js', 
                             JS_ROOT + 'jquery-1.3.1.min.js',),
        'output_filename': 'js/all_compressed.r?.js',
    }
}
COMPRESS_AUTO = True
```

template

```
    {% load compressed %}
    {% compressed_css 'css_all' %}
    {% compressed_js 'js_all' %}
```

My CSS is loading fine but not the javascript. However, When I manually enter the JS sources in my template like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ JS_ROOT }}/js/jquery-1.3.1.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ JS_ROOT }}/js/jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.min.js"</script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ JS_ROOT }}/js/daterangepicker.jQuery.js"></script>
```

I am able to get my javascript date widget working.

Could this be something to do with Django-compress messing the javascript code when it tries to compress it?

Answer (score 0):

Django-compress is searching for CSS and JS files in MEDIA_ROOT so im sure there is a problem. Also u can specify prefix in [extra_context](http://code.google.com/p/django-compress/wiki/Configuration)